# Filter max of rn

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2005, window-functions

How to filter max of rn here

```
select  *
from    (
        select  *
        ,       row_number() over (partition by name order by ox asc) as rn
        from    YourTable
        ) as SubQueryAlias
where   rn = 1
```

above its filering `rn = 1`

I want to filter `rn = max(rn)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `order by ox asc` to `order by ox desc` and use `rn = 1`

```
select  *
from    (
        select  *
        ,       row_number() over (partition by name order by ox desc) as rn
        from    YourTable
        ) as SubQueryAlias
where   rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this to get rn = max(rn):

```
select top 1 * from 
( select * , 
    row_number() over (partition by name order by ox asc) 
    as rn from YourTable ) 
as SubQueryAlias 
order by rn desc
```